# I cant get my labels to change automatically with Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to programming and have been trying to make this project with the Raspberry Pi for over a year now. The problem is I can't seem to get my labels to change automatically. I've tried Clock.schedule_interval but it does nothing. Maybe I've been trying in the wrong place?

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.clock import Clock

def currtempa():
    tfile = open(r"/home/pi/loftpi/w1_slave")
    text = tfile.read() 
    tfile.close() 
    secondline = text.split("\n")[1] 
    temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9] 
    temperature = float(temperaturedata[2:]) 
    temperature = temperature / 1000
    temperature = round(temperature, 1)
    temperature = float(temperature)
    return temperature  
    Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: currtempa(), 0.5)

def outtempa():
    tfile = open(r"/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0315907fa7ff/w1_slave")
    text = tfile.read() 
    tfile.close() 
    secondline = text.split("\n")[1] 
    temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9] 
    temperature = float(temperaturedata[2:]) 
    temperature = temperature / 1000
    temperature = round(temperature, 1)
    temperature = float(temperature)
    return temperature  

class MainWidget(Widget):
    def tempten(args):
        f = open(r"/var/bin/thermostat", "r+")
        value = float(f.read())
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(str(10.0))
    def tempfifteen(args):
        f = open(r"/var/bin/thermostat", "r+")
        value = float(f.read())
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(str(15.0))
    def tempseventeen(args):
        f = open(r"/var/bin/thermostat", "r+")
        value = float(f.read())
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(str(17.0))
    def tempeightteen(args):
        f = open(r"/var/bin/thermostat", "r+")
        value = float(f.read())
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(str(18.0))
    def tempnineteen(args):
        f = open(r"/var/bin/thermostat", "r+")
        value = float(f.read())
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(str(19.0))
    def temptwenty(args):
        f = open(r"/var/bin/thermostat", "r+")
        value = float(f.read())
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(str(20.0))
    def temptwentyone(args):
        f = open(r"/var/bin/thermostat", "r+")
        value = float(f.read())
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(str(21.0))
    def temptwentytwo(args):
        f = open(r"/var/bin/thermostat", "r+")
        value = float(f.read())
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(str(22.0))
    def settemp(args):
        f = open(r"/var/bin/thermostat", "r+")
        value = float(f.read())
        return value
    outtemp = outtempa()
    currtemp = currtempa()


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myApp().run()
```

**My kv**

```
#:kivy 1.9.2


<MainWidget>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'images/home.png'
    GridLayout:
        size: root.size
        rows:3

        BoxLayout:
            size: self.size

            Label:
                id: current
                text: str(root.currtemp)
            Label:
                id: status
                text: ""
                Image:
                    source: 'images/flame.png'
                    center:self.parent.center
                    allow_stretch: True
            Label:
                id: outside
                text: str(root.outtemp)

        BoxLayout:
            size: self.size

            Label:
                id: sett
                text: str(root.settemp()) 

        BoxLayout:
            size: self.size
            spacing: 30 
            padding: 30
            size_hint_y: .70

            Button:
                on_press: root.tempten()
                id: ten
                Image:
                    source: 'images/10.png'
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    allow_stretch: True
                    size: 65, 65  

            Button:
                on_press: root.tempfifteen()
                id: fifteen
                Image:
                    source: 'images/15.png'
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    allow_stretch: True
                    size: 65, 65
            Button:
                on_press: root.tempseventeen()
                id: seventeen
                Image:
                    source: 'images/17.png'
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    allow_stretch: True
                    size: 65, 65
            Button:
                on_press: root.tempeightteen()
                id: eighteen
                Image:
                    source: 'images/18.png'
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    allow_stretch: True
                    size: 65, 65
            Button:
                on_press: root.tempnineteen()
                id: nineteen
                Image:
                    source: 'images/19.png'
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    allow_stretch: True
                    size: 65, 65
            Button:
                on_press: root.temptwenty()
                id: twenty
                Image:
                    source: 'images/20.png'
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    allow_stretch: True
                    size: 65, 65
            Button:
                on_press: root.temptwentyone()
                id: twentyone
                Image:
                    source: 'images/21.png'
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    allow_stretch: True
                    size: 65, 65
            Button:
                on_press: root.temptwentytwo()
                id: twentytwo
                Image:
                    source: 'images/22.png'
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    allow_stretch: True
                    size: 65, 65
```

Comment: It looks like most of your functions differ only in a single number. Instead of writing dozens of function with a different number hardcoded you can write a function that takes the number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make outtemp and currtemp as StringProperty()

Like this:

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class MainWidget(Widget):

    outtemp = StringProperty()
    currtemp = StringProperty()
```

Make sure the functions return strings

```
return str(temperature)
```

That said, I would write this a bit different.

In this case I would make the functions as class methods instead of having global functions.
And then initiate the clock inside the class. That way you can do something like this.

```
def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super(MainWidget,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.currtempa, 0.5)

def currtempa(self,*args):
    """code"""
    self.currtemp = str(ctemp)
```